# How to align buttons side by side in groups of three, best way?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am trying to maintain our website careers page and I know just enough to be dangerous and keep it updated, but I am needing help with how to align all these job listings next to each other in stacked groups of three. It was like this before but it got deleted so I have no reference, thanks.

What I have:
  [image: 1]

What I want:
  [What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzjM.png)

```
<div>
            <a href="/careers/job_listing_4"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Psychologist</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Rock</p>
                </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
            <a href="/careers/job_listing_1"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Psychiatric Nurse Practitioner</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Craw</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_2"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Licensed Clinical Social Worker</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Crawf</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_3"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Licensed Clinical Social Worker</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Cay</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
     <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_5"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Dental Assistant</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Cay</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
     <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_6"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Bilingual Medical Receptionist</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Craw</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
     <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_7"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Certified Medical Assistant/Licensed Practical Nurse</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Ter</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_8.php"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Dental Office Coordinator</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Cay</p>
      </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_9"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Call Center</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Cli</p>
     </div></a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/careers/job_listing_10"><div class="content-tile">
            <p>Nurse Practitioner</p>
            <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Blo</p>
     </div></a>
    </div>

That's the code, it's pretty basic, it used to be arranged in groups of two or three side by side, depending on how many job listings were posted, but that has been removed and I can't remember what it was.
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question so we can see the code you're working with.

Comment: Just a heads up you're closing the `div` before the `a` tag even though the `a` tag should close before the divs.

Comment: It seems to work, what will it change if I put it before?

Comment: @Rivers87 way delayed reply but just because it works doesn't mean it's correct. A lot of systems will complain about that. React for example would not allow it. Think of it as having a house. The walls of the house are the div and the <a> is a couch. If you have the <a> close outside the <div> it's like having a couch going through a wall of the house. It breaks the nested structure of different elements. Picture a box wrapping around the <a>. the <a> should be nested completely inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either Flexbox or CSS Grid for this particular layout without having to include any frameworks; since you want them to be aligned in both directions (rows and columns) I'd definitely suggest sticking to CSS Grid which is specifically made for those cases.

Using flexbox for the same task is absolutely possible, although requires more work and some clever calculations.

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).  Here, I have a grid which will have three rows of equal size, and automatically makes columns as needed depending on how many grid elements I have.  Obviously, you can change the grid properties to fit your own needs :)

```css
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
  .grid-element {
    width: 4rem;
    height: 2rem;
    margin: 0.2rem;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
    <div class="grid-element"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) in your project and use their grid system.
Your code will look like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="/careers/job_listing_4"><div class="content-tile">
     <p>Psychologist</p>
     <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Rock</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="/careers/job_listing_1"><div class="content-tile">
     <p>Psychiatric Nurse Practitioner</p>
     <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Craw</p></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <a href="/careers/job_listing_2"><div class="content-tile">
     <p>Licensed Clinical Social Worker</p>
     <img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/><p>Crawf</p></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, Bootstrap will handle the responsiveness for you.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<style>
.makeInline {
display: inline-block;
width: calc( 25% - 5px );
border: 1px solid red;
margin-bottom: 5px;
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_4">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Psychologist</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Rock</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_1">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Psychiatric Nurse Practitioner</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Craw</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_2">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Licensed Clinical Social Worker</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Crawf</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_3">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Licensed Clinical Social Worker</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Cay</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_5">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Dental Assistant</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Cay</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_6">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Bilingual Medical Receptionist</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Craw</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div class="makeInline">
<a href="/careers/job_listing_7">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Certified Medical Assistant/Licensed Practical Nurse</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Ter</p>
</div>
</a> </div>
<div class="makeInline"> <a href="/careers/job_listing_8.php">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Dental Office Coordinator</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Cay</p>
</div>
</a> </div>
<div class="makeInline"> <a href="/careers/job_listing_9">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Call Center</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Cli</p>
</div>
</a> </div>
<div class="makeInline"> <a href="/careers/job_listing_10">
<div class="content-tile">
<p>Nurse Practitioner</p>
<img src="/images/careers/location_pointer.png"/>
<p>Blo</p>
</div>
</a> </div>
```

Comment: This is closer to what I want but there is a red outline around the boxes, and they resize weird and cutoff text when you resize the browser window. Your help is appreciated though!

Comment: please update this part of code `<style>
.makeInline {
display: inline-block;
width: calc( 25% - 5px );
margin-bottom: 5px;
vertical-align: top;
}
@media (max-width:767px){
  .makeInline {
    width: calc( 50% - 5px );
  }
}
@media (max-width:500px){
  .makeInline {
    width: calc( 100% - 5px );
  }
}
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple grid system will help here, flexbox grid is what I have used in the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/andrwrbnsn/xjt9Lhe7/82/

This essentially lets you set different widths depending on browsers width, these will sit next to each other.

The reason why your blocks don't sit next to eachother are because `<div>` is a block level element, if you set `display: inline-block` it will sit next to eachother.